# Is there an online photo alignment tool?

Tags: web, image-alignment

I would like to align two photographs that were taken from slightly different angles (the very same step that is performed before HDR creation).

Anyone knows of the (online would be the best) tool that would allow me to align photos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Never seen this online, it takes a LOT of processing power*.

There is a free one that comes with [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) tough. It is called [align_image_stack](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Align_image_stack.html).